# Why arm64 pass params throught register x8-x17?

Tags: android-ndk, arm64, cpu-registers

as I know, Arm64 pass params in a function depend on x0-x7 register.
but i test it in a demo, i observerd x8-x15 can be used for pass params.
why it different with https://developer.arm.com/documentation

test on device Android 11, Arm64

```
int sp1 = register_params_test(0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, body, dataHeader, &dh, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18,
                               0x19, 0x110,
                               0x111, 0x112, 0x113, 0x114, 0x115);
```

[image]

Comment: How do you know that `x8-x15` weren't just used as intermediates for those values while they were being placed on the stack?

Comment: @Michael i got your point, jsut check the Arm64 assemble, the register x8-x15 was used for store the value temply, and the real value is pass by register             
.text:0000000000013304                 LDR             W9, [X29,#arg_8]
.text:0000000000013308                 LDR             W10, [X29,#arg_10]
.text:000000000001330C                 LDR             W11, [X29,#arg_18]

Comment: How the caller puts the values on the stack is completely irrelevant.  `register_params_test` can only assume that the first 8 parameters are in registers.  The remaining arguments will be on the stack; they may be elsewhere, but that's no part of the contract.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

these register were used in the function before I print the register values,
so it's not the real params

thanks Michael